# La búsqueda solo devuelve la primera fila en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

En la aplicación que estoy realizando, tengo un estado de cuenta de banco del cual debo buscar desde otra tabla el número de transacción, la fecha y el valor: si encuentro las transacciones en el estado de cuenta debo cambiar un campo mysql llamado *confirmado*. Al realizar la búsqueda con like `%$documento%` encuentra solo la primera transacción del bucle pero no las demás que aún existen en la otra tabla y también están en el estado de cuenta.

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
            $sql='';
            $result='';
            $num++;
            //captura solo los créditos
            if($sheet->getCell("D".$row)->getValue() === 'C'){
                $documento='';
                $fecha_stdo_cta='';

                $fecha_stdo_cta = $sheet->getCell("A" . $row)->getValue();
                $fecha_stdo_cta = formatoFecha($fecha_stdo_cta);
                $documento = $sheet->getCell("E" . $row)->getValue();
                $valor = $sheet->getCell("G" . $row)->getValue();

                //Se almacena el nombre del estado de cuenta y si se encuentra el item
                //Tengo que leer cada uno de los recibos_cli y que el campo confirmado y descartado sea 0


                $sql = "SELECT id_cliente,documento FROM recibos_cli WHERE documento LIKE '%$documento%' AND fecha_recibo='$fecha_stdo_cta' AND confirmado=0 AND descartado=0 AND delop=1";
                //$sql = "SELECT * FROM recibos_cli WHERE confirmado=0 AND descartado=0 AND delop=1";
                $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
                $usuarios = array();

                $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                if($fila === NULL){
                    return;
                }
                echo "la fecha es $fecha_stdo_cta y documento es $documento<br>";
            }

            echo json_encode($usuarios);
        }
```

Comment: Por favor, muéstranos el código de tu query

Comment: Agrega las tablas implicadas (preferiblemente solo las columnas importantes) y alguna data de ejemplo. Agrega además el fragmento de código donde haces la consulta y cómo la estás desplegando en la salida.

Comment: Con mis dotes de adivinación intuyo que puedes tener uno de estos tres típicos problemas: 1) la consulta que realizas está usando un LIMIT 1 (dudo que sea esa ciertamente) o bien 2) Estas asignando a una variable el fetch de la consulta sin pasarlo por un bucle, con lo cual solo devuelve el primero, o bien 3) Dentro del bucle `while` donde asignas la fila al fetch estas sobreescribiendo todo el rato la misma variable.  Como dices que solo encuentras la primera transacción me inclino por el punto 2. ¿he acertado algo? Puedes [edit] la pregunta y agregar el código para comprobarlo.

Comment: Vale, como decia, era el punto 2

Comment: pues masterguro no es nada de lo que me indicas alli publique el codigo, gracias de todas formas por la ayuda

Comment: Vaya, tampoco es que tu código tenga mucho que ver tu pregunta... donde está el `like %$traccion%`?

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, es lo que decia entre mis adivinaciones, el punto 2.

Comment: Aún asi, superado ese punto, veo muchos más problemas despues, pues no haces nada con esos datos, y tambien parece que el array $usuarios no lo uses para nada, y finalizas enviandolo (vacio) con un echo json_encode.  Me imagino que estabas encallado en ese punto y el resto aun lo tienes que pulir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo consigues un resultado porque estas haciendo esto:

```
$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
```

lo cual solo asigna la primera fila de la consulta a esa variable, obviando el resto.

Para conseguir el resto debes hacerlo asi:

```
$todas = [];
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $todas[] = $fila;
}
print_r($todas);
```

de este modo estas agregando al *array* **$todas** las filas una a una que vas recorriendo de **$result**, y luego puedes tratarlo como te convenga, o bien hacer lo que quieras dentro del `while`, pero una a una.

Comment: solo me responde array vacios sin embargo en la tabla recibos_cli he registrado mas iten validos pero no los encuenta solo el primero otra vez Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id_cliente] => 1
            [documento] => 00053926111
        )

)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
Array
(
)

Comment: Pues eso quiere decir que solo encuentra una coincidencia de esa consulta en la primera pasada del bucle superior `for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {` y en el resto no encuentra ni una sola.  Deberias comprobar la consulta a mano para ver si realmente en alguna salen más de un registro (si tan solo sale uno en cada ciclo del bucle superior entonces no necesitas mi respuesta, esta claro, ya lo hacias bien)

Comment: Les agradezco y de antemano a @masterguru, ya que si funciono lo que vi que es el like que no busca el char cuando el campo no lleva los 00 a la izquierda que existen en el estado de cuenta, eso aun no se como solucionarlo ;-(

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado :-) Hazle caso a @padaleiana y elimina esta respuesta, y abre una nueva pregunta con esta nueva problemática que tienes, pues si vamos encadenando los nuevos errores en la misma pregunta al final no servirá para nadie que la visite después.  Si mi respuesta ha solucionado tu pregunta deberias aceptarla para que la comunidad lo sepa y pueda encontrar la respuesta útil a tu pregunta. Así no quedará pendiente eternamente. En este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas y el porque es importante hacerlo, gracias.

Comment: En cuanto a tu nueva problemática, como pista, mira la función [intval()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.intval.php), la cual convierte a números cadenas de texto (y así eliminas los 0 a la izquierda si esas cadenas son solo números... pero si son números y letras entonces nada, hay que hacerlo de otra forma... por lo tanto nueva pregunta!)